Why does Lollar Special T bridge pickup sound hotter while DC resistance read high?
Why does Lollar Special T bride pickup sound hotter while DC resistance reads high?
Lollar pickups site gives the AV. resistance: 8Kohm
People say it's a hotter sounding pickup, I think it truly sounds bigger than its pairing neck pickup which only reads 6.3K .
Why is that, am I getting it right?

There is a link "Read about DC resistance" on the product page that you link that explains it. I'll make a short summary here:

The resistance doesn't directly make the pickup "hot" or high output
Increasing the strength of magnetic field or inductance of the coil makes the output higher
One way to increase inductance is to increase the number of turns in the coil (but core material and geometry of the coil and core play a part too)
The DC resistance is directly proportional to length of wire (assuming same wire gauge), which in turn is directly proportional to number of turns (assuming same coil geometry, etc)
The result is that for otherwise similar pickups, higher turn count produces both higher output and higher DC resistance. Since the actual output is difficult to measure, DC resistance is used as an approximate measure.

